# Play Audio on Android

Tags: android, audio, mp3

Answers to many questions about this theme doesn't help me! It's not the problem that audio needs to be started first by a click or any other type of action.

I want to Play a number of different short mp3's on my website. The best approach I've found is the following. It works on Internet Explorer and Chrome (other Desktop browsers not tested) and on mobile devices with iOS. But not on Android.

In my html I initialize an audio device:

```
<audio id="mp3play" src=""></audio>
```

It's only for defining the name "mp3play".

In the header of the html I have the following javascript:

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
<!--
function play(name) {
        var oAudio = document.getElementById("mp3play");
        oAudio.stop;
        oAudio.src = name;
        oAudio.play();
}

//-->
```

Now I can invoke the player with the following link:

```
<a href="javascript:play('stuff/voc/WAVvow/011001.MP3');"
```

This works fine, even on Android.

But for special requirements I do not use filenames for mp3's. I've made a Perl script to deliver the pm3 data depending on a computation. For this I use the following link:

```
<a href="javascript:play('../cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?185004');"
```

This Perl code "playmp3.pl" sends a header and then the complete mp3 data:

```
    ($entry[0] has a pointer to the desired data, $entry[1] the length)
    open(DAT, "<../wbtde/DictData/dv8.dat");
    binmode DAT;
    seek(DAT, $entry[0], 0);
    read(DAT, $mp3, $entry[1]);       # Lesen des Eintrages
    close DAT;
    print "Content-type: audio/mpeg\n\n"; 
    print $mp3;
```

Also this works fine on IE, Chrome and iOS browsers, but not on Android.

I can invoke the script also directly with

```
www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?185004
```

Also this is working fine on IE, Chrome and iOS browser, but not on Android. Android tells me it can not play this type of content. But with content type audio/mpeg3 it's also not playing.

This is the Android error log when I tap one link only:

```
            D/CDX_Player( 2402): >>>>>>>> CedarX Player Version: 00010707
            I/CedarPlayerWrapper( 2402): setDataSource('http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?062013')
            I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource( 2402): connect to http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?062013 @0
            W/MediaPlayer(  967): info/warning (701, 0)
            I/MediaPlayer(  967): Info (701,0)
            D/sft_http_stream( 2402): reset stream
            I/NuCachedSource2( 2402): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
            W/demux_http( 2402): unknown file format!
            E/demux_http( 2402): open error, destroy stream handle
            E/DemuxSftNetwork_Component( 2402): cedar demuxer open error
            E/CedarXPlayer( 2402): CedarXPlayer:prepare error!
            E/MediaPlayer(  967): error (1, -2147483648)
            E/MediaPlayer(  967): Error (1,-2147483648)
            I/CDX_Player( 2402): cancel prepare!
            D/CDX_Player( 2402): >>>>>>>> CedarX Player Version: 00010707
            I/CedarPlayerWrapper( 2402): setDataSource('http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?062013')
            W/MediaPlayer(  967): info/warning (701, 0)
            I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource( 2402): connect to http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?062013 @0
            I/MediaPlayer(  967): Info (701,0)
            D/sft_http_stream( 2402): reset stream
            I/NuCachedSource2( 2402): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
            W/demux_http( 2402): unknown file format!
            E/demux_http( 2402): open error, destroy stream handle
            E/DemuxSftNetwork_Component( 2402): cedar demuxer open error
            E/CedarXPlayer( 2402): CedarXPlayer:prepare error!
            E/MediaPlayer(  967): error (1, -2147483648)
            E/MediaPlayer(  967): Error (1,-2147483648)
            I/CDX_Player( 2402): cancel prepare!
```

Another try:
I've saved the output from Perl script to a file with the name "test.MP3". Then I've prepared a link in my html as

```
<a href="javascript:play('stuff/test.MP3');"
```

This works on Android! So I can assume that the output of the Perl script is correct.

Is it a question of content type?

Is it a question of the filename (.pl instead of mp3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Filename!

Fortunately Android accepts the addition ".mp3" to the Perl call:

```
www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/playmp3.pl?185004.mp3
```

I've changed the Perl script to remove that addition and now it works on all platforms.